# Facebook Integration Authentication Error:-Invalid key hash. The key hash K/MLFPcpd4lHR56HLtn9eYQ3pjQ does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

This is the code execute on click of the button.

```
public void handleSharing() { if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) { // Publish the post using the Share Dialog FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this) .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android") .setApplicationName("SharingApp") .build(); uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present()); } else { // Fallback. For example, publish the post using the Feed Dialog publishFeedDialog(); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this method and get Key hash and then add this hash key to your application registered over developer.facebook.com:-
`public static void showHashKey(Context context) {`

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.sharingapplication", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); //Your            package name here
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
}
```